# Matlab 2014b switch C compiler from Clang to GCC on Mac

Tags: macos, matlab, gcc

I type
`mex -setup C`
in MATLAB 2014b and it shows
`MEX configured to use 'Xcode with Clang' for C language compilation.`

And it doesn't give me options to select. I am sure I have installed GCC on my Mac.

I want to unlink the Xcode and switch the compiler to GCC.
Can somebody tell me how to do that?

thanks,

Comment: Is gcc supported for Mac? I can only see that LLVM is supported, but I may be wrong. [Supported compilers](http://se.mathworks.com/support/compilers/R2014b/index.html?sec=maci64)

Comment: There is a release for Mac.

Comment: I understand that, but it is rather if matlab supports the compiler. Looking at MATLAB supported compilers, I cannot see that GCC is supported. The conclusion could then be that mex cannot use GCC for Mac, but again I am not sure about this. You may want to ask this question on matlab answers as well. You should also make sure that you have a 64-bit compiler for matlab 64-bit and so on.

Comment: Install gcc via homebrew and follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28970935/osx-replace-gcc-version-4-2-1-with-4-9-installed-via-homebrew/28982564#28982564

Comment: Install gcc via homebrew and follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28970935/osx-replace-gcc-version-4-2-1-with-4-9-installed-via-homebrew/28982564#28982564