# OSX - replace gcc version 4.2.1 with 4.9 installed via Homebrew

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, homebrew

This has been plaguing me for awhile now. I am trying to compile a huge C++ file (I know it works as I it works fine on my Arch Linux computer at work). When I checked my GCC version on my mac It returns the following

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.57) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.1.0
Thread model: posix
```

I have also installed the most recent GCC version using Homebrew with

```
brew install gcc49
```

My question now is how do I apply that newly installed GCC version to be the default version that the terminal uses?

I am also aware that when you use homebrew to isntall gcc it names it gcc-49 so that there is no confusion between packages.

I have no idea how to replace the 4.2.1 version that comes with XCode with the 4.9 version I have installed.

Thanks

Edit:
Switched to my mac to get the full return statement of gcc --version

Edit 2: 
My end game here is to be able to navigate to the directory and be able to type

```
make
sudo make install
```

to install the daemon that has been made. Right now that returns tons of errors with random packages and the Standard Library

Comment: Unchecked, but I guess you just run `/usr/local/bin/gcc` and make sure `/usr/local/bin` is near the start of your PATH.

Comment: Not exactly sure what that means. I am extremely new with the mac terminal and how to do anything with it. I added this if that means anything to you
echo "PATH=\"/usr/local/bin:$PATH\"" > ~/.bash_profile

Comment: Try `/usr/local/bin/gcc --version`

Comment: That exact line doesn't work, however 

    /usr/local/bin/gcc-4.9 --version

returns

    gcc-4.9 (Homebrew gcc49 4.9.2_1) 4.9.2
    Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
    This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
    warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Comment: So edit your `~/.bash_profile` so it says `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH` and then start a new Terminal and try again like this `gcc-4.9 --version`

Comment: I get the same errors and gcc --version still returns 4.2. I also have PATH="/usr/local/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin" in my ~/.bash_profile though. Should that be removed?

Comment: Try `gcc-4.9 --version`

Comment: That works with the long PATH that is currently in there, as well as with your export

Comment: Good so you are all working now. If you want the simple command `gcc` to invoke your gcc-4.9, do this `cd /usr/local/bin; ls gcc` if nothing shows up you can do `ln -s gcc-4.9  gcc` and that will become your default gcc.

Comment: Thanks! running make in the directory doesn't work so I will look into that next. Could you post that the export and the last comment you made as an answer and I will mark it as correct

Answer (score 72, accepted):

By default, `homebrew` places the executables (binaries) for the packages it installs into `/usr/local/bin` - which is a pretty sensible place for binaries installed by local users when you think about it - compared to `/bin` which houses standardisded binaries belonging to the core OS. So, your `brew` command should have installed `gcc-4.9` into `/usr/local/bin`. The question is now how to use it... you have several options.

**Option 1**

If you just want to compile one or two things today and tomorrow, and then probably not use the compiler again, you may as well just invoke the `gcc` installed by `homebrew` with the full path like this:

```
/usr/local/bin/gcc-4.9 --version
```

**Option 2**

If you are going to be using `gcc` quite a lot, it gets a bit tiresome explicitly typing the full path every time, so you could put the following into your `~/.bash_profile`

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

and then start a new Terminal and it will know it needs to look in `/usr/local/bin`, so you will be able to get away with simply typing

```
gcc-4.9 --version
```

**Option 3**

If you just want to use `gcc` to invoke the compiler, without worrying about the actual version, you can do Option 2 above and additionally create a symbolic link like this

```
cd /usr/local/bin
ln -s  gcc-4.9  gcc
```

That will allow you to run the `homebrew`-installed `gcc` by simply typing `gcc` at the command line, like this

```
gcc --version
```

**Note:**

If you later want to install, say `gcc-4.13` or somesuch, you would do your `brew install` as before, then change the symbolic link like this:

```
cd /usr/local/bin
rm gcc               # remove old link from gcc to gcc-4.9
ln -s gcc-4.13 gcc   # make new link from gcc to gcc-4.13
```

---

Note that if you are actually using `C++` rather than `C`, you will need to adapt the above for `g++` in place of `gcc`.

Comment: After setting a symbolic link I would recommend closing the terminal and open a new, then write gcc -v. Mac osx shew in the old terminal window that nothing has changed.

Comment: Is it not `.zshrc` or `.zprofile` on MacOS Catalina?

Comment: I had to do the same for g++ to fix my problem

Comment: @Mathy Good thinking - I originally answered for `gcc` and `C` but I guess people could equally be looking for `g++` and `C++` so I added a note at the end. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

simply updating the order of $PATH in ~/.bash_profile to the brew installed version `'export PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/5.1.0/bin:$PATH'` was not enough to make the switch for me

changing the alias in your ~./bash_profile (`alias gcc='gcc-5'`) works, but can be confusing i.e. `which gcc` will return the Clang version

what worked for me was to make a symbolic link in the brew gcc directory as well as update the path (point 1 above)

```
cd /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/5.1.0/bin/gcc
ln -s gcc-5 gcc
```

now `which gcc` returns the correct version 5.1.0

Answer (score 1):

OS X does not come with GCC installed (4.2.1 or otherwise).  Clang is the default system compiler and has been for some time.  It is using the C++ headers from 4.2.1 when invoked as GCC.  Have you tried compiling your code with Clang natively, instead of calling "gcc" (which calls Clang)?  It has more modern headers and C++ support than the GCC emulation mode.

Comment: I did not, simply because the Makefile was created before me and was setup for GCC. The solution to the problem ended up being to `cd /usr/local/bin ln -s gcc-4.9 gcc` as stated by @MarkSetchell

Answer (score 1):

Download the gcc binaries untar and copy the bin, lib include share and libexec files to your /usr directory then type gcc --version this is what i expect you to see

gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.9.2 20141029 (prerelease)
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Comment: This is a really dangerous suggestion, you shouldn't be dropping random stuff in /usr, and while I've never installed gcc and friends from binaries (always from source), I'd expect some sort of installer that puts things in the right places and sets up the various symlinks correctly, etc.