# Mac OS X: Installed and linked gcc 6.2 with Homebrew, but gcc --version still says 4.9.2

Tags: macos, gcc, homebrew

On OS X 10.11.6, I installed gcc 6.2.0 using homebrew.  It lives over in usr/local/Cellar/gcc/6.2.0/bin.  After getting it to link (it didn't do this automagically), I cd there and try the solution from [this other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28970935/osx-replace-gcc-version-4-2-1-with-4-9-installed-via-homebrew/28982564#28982564) to create an alias

> ln -s gcc-6 gcc
>   then gcc --version gives me
>   cc (GCC) 4.9.2 20141029 (prerelease)
>   Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
>   This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
>   warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

All this is because trying to install things crashes because of -rdynamic flags, that I hope is fixed in a newer version.

Comment: check `which gcc`, there must be another gcc in your path before this one.

Comment: `which gcc` `/usr/local/bin/gcc`

Comment: bingo. You have to set your path before that one in your `.profile` or whatever.

Comment: Adding usr/local/Cellar/gcc/6.2.0/bin to my .bash_profile did it, thanks.

Comment: @top1214 hi, how do you install gcc6.2 with brew? I only can get until 6.1 running `brew info homebrew/versions/gcc6`

Comment: Colo, what does `brew outdated` give you?  If it includes gcc, you can then `brew upgrade`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You created the symlink with the proper target name (`gcc`) but forgot to set the `PATH` to your newly installed location (or set it after the system path).

What's confusing is that your system already has a version of gcc installed. You have to override the default path so your `gcc` command comes first.

- edit your `~/.profile` file and check PATH adjustment. Add a line in the end which contains:

  `export PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/6.2.0/bin:$PATH`

Then open a new terminal and ensure that `which gcc` prints

`/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/6.2.0/bin/gcc`