# Mac OSX is using gcc 6.2.0 but g++ 4.9.2

Tags: macos, gcc, g++

I may not understand this completely, but I thought gcc and g++ were basically the same compiler.  I used homebrew to install and link gcc 6.2.0 (see [Mac OS X: Installed and linked gcc 6.2 with Homebrew, but gcc --version still says 4.9.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39518634/mac-os-x-installed-and-linked-gcc-6-2-with-homebrew-but-gcc-version-still-sa) ).

When I say which gcc I get /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/6.2.0/bin/gcc

When I say which g++ I get /usr/local/bin/g++

Did I miss a step or is my understanding way off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to do this:

> cd /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/6.2.0/bin/gcc
>
> ln -s g++-6 g++

which I guess I had previously done for gcc.