# Compiler Flags For C++11 - chrono file not found

Tags: c++, c++11, makefile, flags

I am trying to make a project I downloaded from github.
After setting up all the dependencies, it asks me to run 'make'. However, 'make' fails and complains about `chrono` file not being found.
I understand that it is a compiler related issue and I have to enable c++11 support. More specifically, pass the compiler flag `-stdlib=libc++`.
However, adding this flag to my Makefile still produces the same error. Can anyone explain where/how this flag needs to be set?

this is the content of the Makefile:

```
TARGETS = \ 
    ptools \ 
    feature \ 
    libsvm \ 
    wrapper 

all: 
    -for dir in $(TARGETS); do \ 
    cd $${dir}; $(MAKE); cd ..; \ 
    done cd libsvm; $(MAKE) lib; cd ..; 

clean: 
    -for dir in $(TARGETS); do \ 
    cd $${dir}; $(MAKE) clean; cd ..; \ 
    done 

test: 
    @echo hello; 

.PHONY: clean $(TARGETS)
```

**Update1:** After running `brew install gcc`, it starts downloading the dependencies. However, it always breaks when it's downloading one of the dependencies, mpfr, with this error:  *Error: mpfr cannot be built with any available compilers. Install GNU's GCC.*

**Update2:** I managed to update gcc and the version it returns is 6.2.0. However, I am still seeing the same error.
I added `CXXFLAGS += -stdlib=libc++ -std=gnu++11` to my Makefile, bust still see the same result.

Comment: What compiler (and version) are you using in your dev environment?

Comment: Are you passing `-std=c++11`? You had to do this in GCC and Clang to use C++11 stuff when last i used them.

Comment: The link to the github project could help.

Comment: @SR_ Some makefile details would suffice.

Comment: I had to download xCode, so I believe it is using gcc. the version is 4.2.1.

Comment: Here is the link to the project: https://github.com/Netflix/vmaf

Comment: this is the content of the Makefile:TARGETS = \
 ptools \
 feature \
 libsvm \
 wrapper

all:
 -for dir in $(TARGETS); do \
  cd $${dir}; $(MAKE); cd ..; \
 done

 cd libsvm; $(MAKE) lib; cd ..;

clean:
 -for dir in $(TARGETS); do \
  cd $${dir}; $(MAKE) clean; cd ..; \
 done

test:
 @echo hello;

.PHONY: clean $(TARGETS)

Comment: I can read on project page : it requires gcc and g++ (>=4.8).

Comment: How do I update the gcc?

Comment: @AminAbed Add additional information (like the makefile changes you made) [into your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40773879/edit) please. As comments that's not very useful as you can see.

Comment: @Amin Abed: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28970935/osx-replace-gcc-version-4-2-1-with-4-9-installed-via-homebrew

Comment: @AminAbed _"How do I update the gcc?"_ Depends on your dev environment.

Comment: Put the lines of the error in your message, and enough lines before the error in order to see what's happening.

Answer (score 1):

You should add

```
CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11
```

to your makefile (somewhere prior to the rules).

---

Supposed you have a up to date enough toolchain.

Older compilers support the flags

```
-std=c++0x
```

may be.

---

How to update your toolchain (as you asked for in [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40773879/compiler-flags-for-c11-chrono-file-not-found/40773959#comment68772805_40773879)), depends on your OS environment and software managing system.

At least an option would be to compile the latest (stable) version of your toolchain yourself.