# How to change clang to gcc in MacOs?

Tags: c, macos, gcc, clang

Is it possible to prevent `MacOS` to stop mapping `gcc` to `clang`?

i want to run a tool its dependency is with `gcc` and not for clang. So i installed `gcc` but since i typing in `gcc -v` i am getting the mapped version to clang

how to prevent this?

this is how am i getting

```
Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.17)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.3.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

Comment: Adjust your PATH

Comment: What do you mean? do you mean this: Configured with: --prefix=/

Comment: Are you sure that `gcc` is not just a symbolic link to clang?

Comment: How do i can know that? do you have any solution?

Comment: You’ll need to say something like `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH` depending on where your binary or wrapper is located.

Comment: which value should be instead of  `$PATH`?

Comment: that export command appends a directory to the front of PATH, so that is a string $PATH.  Your desired executable would be in the `/usr/local/bin` directory.

Comment: now lets say the directory has other things you dont want in PATH.  Create a new dir `mkdir /usr/local/catalinasfolder`  link to the tool you want to have be in PATH there `ln -s /usr/local/bin/gcc /usr/local/catalinasfolder/gcc` then export the dir to PATH `export PATH=/usr/local/catalinasfolder:$PATH`  verify with `which gcc`

Comment: @RichardBarber i cant do this: premission denied. But if i try like this `alias gcc='gcc-9'` it works but since i reopen the terminal it goes back to clang

Comment: prepend `sudo` to commands needing higher permission level.

Comment: Check these threads: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64992467/mac-clang-installation-seems-to-override-gcc-install https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28970935/osx-replace-gcc-version-4-2-1-with-4-9-installed-via-homebrew