# Mac clang installation seems to override GCC install

Tags: macos, gcc, clang

Mac 10.13.6 High Sierra here. New to C development and I'm trying to get myself setup with the latest stable/recommended GCC version, which I *believe* (keep me honest here) is 10.2.

When I go to the terminal to see what I have installed:

```
$ gcc --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.1)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
$ gcc -dumpversion
4.2.1
```

OK...surprised to see LLVM/clang-related stuff in the output. So I try this:

```
$ clang --version
Apple LLVM version 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.1)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

So its *almost* as if... I have both `clang` and `gcc` installed, but my `clang` installation has assimilated my GCC installation?! Why else would the `gcc --version` output reference clang?

Is this typical for Mac setups?

**What do I need to do to get GCC 10.2 properly installed on my machine?**

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Here are some simple truths, statements and observations to try and explain what's going on:

- **Apple** ships the `clang/LLVM` compiler with **macOS**. `Clang` is a *"front-end"* that can parse `C`, `C++` and `Objective-C` down to something that `LLVM` (referred to as a *"back-end"*) can compile
- `Clang/LLVM` is located in `/Applications/Xcode.app/somewhere`
- **Apple** also ships a `/usr/bin/gcc` which just runs `clang`. I have no idea why they do that - it doesn't seem very helpful to me - but they don't answer my questions
- Apple puts its binaries (programs) in `/usr/bin`. That is an integral part of **macOS** and you should never touch or change anything in there - you are asking for problems if you do. This warning applies to Python too.

---

If you want the real, lovely **GNU Compiler Collection (GCC)** which includes the `gcc`, `g++` and `gfortran` compilers, your best bet, IMHO, is to get them from [homebrew](https://brew.sh). I will not put the installation instructions here because they could become outdated, so you should use the ones on the **homebrew** site.

Once you have **homebrew** installed, you can install the **GNU Compiler Collection (GCC)** with:

```
brew install gcc
```

After that, you will have all the lovely **GNU Compiler Collection (GCC)** of tools in `/usr/local/bin`, so you should put that in your PATH, near the beginning, and in any case before `/usr/bin`, using:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

In general, you should also add a similar line into your login profile, or into the system login profile, so it is set up every time you or any other user logs in.

Let's take a look:

```
ls /usr/local/bin/gcc* /usr/local/bin/g++*

/usr/local/bin/gcc-10
/usr/local/bin/g++-10
```

Depending on the versions and updates, you will then have these programs available:

```
gcc-10          # the real GNU C compiler
g++-10          # the real GNU C++compiler
gfortran        # GNU fortran compiler
```

And you can check their versions with:

```
gcc-10 -v
g++-10 -v
gfortran -v
```

---

Now you know about **homebrew**, here are some more simple truths and observations:

- folks (who are not the supplier of the operating system) who supply binaries (programs) for you should put their stuff in `/usr/local` to show that it is just a *locally* installed program rather than a part of the core **macOS** operating system
- **homebrew** is well-behaved and installs its binaries (programs) in `/usr/local/Cellar` and then usually makes symbolic links from `/usr/local/bin/PROGRAM` to the Cellar. None of this interferes with Apple-supplied stuff.
- if you want to run the **homebrew** version of a command, you should have `/usr/local/bin` first on your PATH

Let's have a look at those symbolic links:

```
ls -l /usr/local/bin/g*10

lrwxr-xr-x  1 mark  admin  31 21 Aug 16:41 /usr/local/bin/g++-10 -> ../Cellar/gcc/10.2.0/bin/g++-10
lrwxr-xr-x  1 mark  admin  31 21 Aug 16:41 /usr/local/bin/gcc-10 -> ../Cellar/gcc/10.2.0/bin/gcc-10
```

---

If you want to know what you are actually running when you enter a command, use the `type` command like this.

```
type gcc
gcc is hashed (/usr/bin/gcc)
```

That tells you that if you run `gcc` you will actually be running `/usr/bin/gcc` which we know is from **Apple** - because it is in `/usr/bin`

---

Now try this:

```
type gcc-10
gcc-10 is hashed (/usr/local/bin/gcc-10)
```

That tells you that if you run `gcc-10` you will actually be running `/usr/local/bin/gcc-10` which we know is from **homebrew** - because it is in `/usr/local/bin`

Comment: My $PATH has the string `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin` (where local/bin is before bin) - gcc is still clang! `Apple clang version 13.1.6 (clang-1316.0.21.2.3)` (already installed gcc via homebrew)

Comment: Seems like Brew alt changed there path to gcc, it's no longer in /usr/local/bin/

Comment: @Reyomi It is now `/opt/homebrew/bin`, for Apple Silicon Macs at least.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this just by adding these to ~/.zshrc (since I am using zshrc):

```
alias gcc="gcc-12"
alias g++="g++-12"
alias cc="cc-12"
alias c++="c++-12"
```

On the basis that I've installed gcc-12 using homebrew:

```
brew install gcc-12
```

This is what I get running "gcc --version" after using alias:

```
% gcc --version 
gcc-12 (Homebrew GCC 12.2.0) 12.2.0
Copyright (C) 2022 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Plus, you can edit in zshrc using vi:

```
cd
vi ~/.zshrc
```

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed that issue by setting up symbolic links to the GCC:

```bash
ln -s /usr/local/bin/g++-${VERSION} /usr/local/bin/g++
ln -s /usr/local/bin/gcc-${VERSION} /usr/local/bin/gcc
```

GCC installation shouldn't provide that links (there can be a lot of different versions of GCC, so which should be linked?), but `/usr/bin/gcc` exists as Mark Setchell wrote. So if you ask the system for GCC, it will run this one.

Everything should work after adding these links and checking PATH if `/usr/local/bin` is before `/usr/bin/gcc`.

It works for me even on GitHub Actions MacOS job.