# Why do `gcc -v` and `whereis gcc` output different paths?

Tags: c++, gcc

I get the following output when I run respectively `gcc -v` and `whereis gcc`:

```
Apple clang version 13.1.6 (clang-1316.0.21.2.3)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin21.4.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

```
gcc: /usr/bin/gcc
```

Does this mean I have multiple installations of `gcc` on my mac ? If so, how do I uninstall the 'extra/unnecessary' ones ?

Thanks

Comment: Well, why don't you take a look at what `/usr/bin/gcc` actually is, and see if this Scooby-Doo mystery can be easily solved. What does `ls -al /usr/bin/gcc` come back with?

Comment: `stat` the two paths and/or do `readlink -e` on both paths. I suspect they may actually be the same file. How much trouble macOS goes to to pretend otherwise I don't know.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Well... it's not a symlink so I'm not really sure where to go from here Detective

Comment: @ShadowRanger Thanks now I see it. Was it a symlink after all then ?

Comment: @sleepydrmike: The directories themselves could be symlinks, not just `gcc` itself. `readlink -e` unravels *all* symlinks along the path, which helps (though it doesn't help with hard links if those are involved). Or the same file system could be remounted with different roots. *shrugs* I don't use macOS, so I can't say what nonsense they're doing here.

Comment: OT: Maybe I'm too nitpicking, but you may have [*no*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64992467/mac-clang-installation-seems-to-override-gcc-install) installation of GCC at all on your mac.

Comment: Please see ["Use whereis can not find the file in the Mac"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/287467/use-whereis-can-not-find-the-file-in-the-mac) over at `stackexchange`.