Why is ARM NEON SIMD Sum is slower than serial sum?
I have been trying to benchmark memory bandwidth  on my M2 Mac and one thing I noticed that when I try to use ARM NEON SIMD it seems that it has a slower processing time and lower memory bandwidth. This is my code:
int arm_neon_simd_sum(const std::vector<int8_t>& arr) {
    // Check if the array is empty
    if (arr.empty()) return 0;

    int32x4_t v_sum = vdupq_n_s32(0); // Initialize NEON vector to hold partial sums
    size_t i = 0;

    // Process the array in chunks of 16 elements
    for (; i + 15 < arr.size(); i += 16) {
        int8x16_t v_data = vld1q_s8(&arr[i]); // Load 16 elements into a NEON register

        // Convert int8x16_t to int16x8_t
        int16x8_t v_data_low = vmovl_s8(vget_low_s8(v_data)); // Lower 8 elements to int16
        int16x8_t v_data_high = vmovl_s8(vget_high_s8(v_data)); // Upper 8 elements to int16

        // Convert int16x8_t to int32x4_t and accumulate
        v_sum = vaddq_s32(v_sum, vpaddlq_s16(v_data_low));
        v_sum = vaddq_s32(v_sum, vpaddlq_s16(v_data_high));
    }

    // Horizontal add the vector to get the sum of all elements
    int32_t sum_array[4];
    vst1q_s32(sum_array, v_sum);

    int sum = sum_array[0] + sum_array[1] + sum_array[2] + sum_array[3];

    // Handle the remaining elements
    for (; i < arr.size(); ++i) {
        sum += arr[i];
    }

    return sum;
}


And here are my testing result:
2024-07-12 21:31:51.101 -------- running arm_neon_simd_sum --------
....................................................................................................
2024-07-12 21:32:03.808 Result: 536870900
2024-07-12 21:32:03.808 Total execution time: 12.705522168999996 seconds
2024-07-12 21:32:03.808 Total bytes processed: 107374182400
2024-07-12 21:32:03.808 Throughput: 7.870593484460515 GB/s

And In comparison a naive serial sum seems to be faster:
Code:
int sum_sequential(const std::vector<int8_t> &arr) {
  int sum = 0;
  for (int64_t i = 0; i < kArraySize; i++) {
    sum += arr[i];
  }
  return sum;
}

Result:
2024-07-13 10:28:54.706 -------- running sequential sum --------
....................................................................................................
2024-07-12 21:31:02.750 Result: 536870900
2024-07-12 21:31:02.750 Total execution time: 3.303718871999998 seconds
2024-07-12 21:31:02.750 Total bytes processed: 107374182400
2024-07-12 21:31:02.750 Throughput: 30.268919322261286 GB/s
2024-07-12 21:31:02.750 -------- running random access sum -------

I am wondering why? Am I doing something wrong with my SIMD code that are slowing my code down?
Note this is with -O3 so I do think some auto vectorization might be happening for serial code, so my main concern is how can I achieve the performance of that level with my own code?
Full code can be found here: https://godbolt.org/z/rc5vT9nTM

How are you doing the "serial" summation? Please try to create a proper [mre] to show us.

@Someprogrammerdude the full code is linked in the end

That code differ from the code shown in this question, how can we then trust this (or the linked) code or the results you claim to get? And remember that questions needs to be self-contained. What happens if the link becomes invalid?

@Someprogrammerdude I edit my question, and thanks for policing the SO community.

Anyway what seems to happen is that you have a loop-carried dependency through several sadalp, and the auto-vectorized version uses saddw and saddw2, but also all tied up with serial dependencies, so to me that doesn't quite explain the difference. If I compile with Clang I get a different result that looks like it's auto-vectorized better, with multiple accumulators to break up the dependencies. Are you actually using Clang? Keep this in mind: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64992467/555045

@user555045 yeah I realized that I am using clang++ not g++. I will update the link to better reflect my setup. But still what confuses me is that the hand written code seems to do what auto-vec would do but some how got beaten by it.

Please show not just the function you are studying, but a complete program including the benchmarking code. Sometimes a function gets optimized in unexpected ways depending on how it's called.

@BobFang it's different though. For example, and I think this is what matters most, your version got compiled into a serial chain of sadalp - so limited by their latency, not their throughput. The auto-vectorized version uses as many as 8 independent accumulators, it may be entirely throughput-limited.

Don’t use Neon instructions directly. First, they don’t work on Intel Macs. Second, you force the compiler to literally follow your instructions.
Use just the clang short vector types (for example double with two, four or eight values per vector), and let the compiler worry about optimisation. It is more portable, more readable, easier to write and usually faster.

yeah I agree, I am not trying to create production code to be honest, this is more learning and educational code for myself.

This doesn't answer the question which is "why".
